# Replicate pandas grouped string join

Tags: python, join, group-by, datatable, py-datatable

Hi there I would like to join all strings within a group with Python datatable in order to avoid pandas. Below is the code I am currently using and which I would like to replicate in datatable.

Does anyone know how to do it? Thank you very much!

```
from datatable import dt, f, by

df = dt.Frame(group1=[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], group2=[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3], text=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'])

df = df.to_pandas()
df2 = df.groupby(['group1', 'group2'])['text'].apply(' '.join).reset_index() # replicate this with datatable

df:
   group1  group2 text
0       1       1    a
1       1       1    b
2       1       2    c
3       2       2    d
4       2       2    e
5       2       3    f

df2 
   group1  group2 text
0       1       1  a b
1       1       2    c
2       2       2  d e
3       2       3    f
```

Comment: Why are you avoiding pandas?

Comment: 1. This fails when I use np.where() or df.loc[] before doing this operation. 2. I prefer datatable

Comment: It shouldn't fail. I'd focus on fixing that issue.

Comment: @gshpychka I already did, the error is very cumbersome.... `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found`

Comment: You should post a new question with the full error, while providing the code to reproduce it.

Comment: Well the goal is anyway to use datatable. Not just for this one but in general

Comment: For strings, at the moment, it is not possible to replicate string join/aggregate yet within datatable. I guess once the UDF functionality is impletemented, this should be relatively easy

Comment: user-defined function feature request: https://github.com/h2oai/datatable/issues/1960